# Reference request on statistical convergence, asymptotics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, asymptotics

I'm looking for good literature on asymptotics in statistics.

I've learned about alsmost sure convergence, convergence in probability, convergence in law, $O_p, o_p$, etc... Definitions, theorems and limited examples.

But besides the definitions I don't feel that I get what the *true meaning* of these concepts implies...

Can someone give me a good reference which truly explains these concepts by means of **graphs**, **intuition** and perhaps **simulation**.